# How to update changed database password in Liferay6.06?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay, liferay-6

I have a setup liferay6.06 version in my ubuntu system, its working fine, I am using the mysql database,before changing database password its working fine, after that I have changed database password,i have updated the changed password in portal.properties,while starting the tomcat server it is not connecting to the database and server is started. while accessing url iam getting 404 error. what are the places i need to update the changed password in liferay 6.06?

Comment: You need to update password in portal-ext.properties

Comment: where can i create and how to create portal-ext.properties?

Comment: inside "liferay-portal\tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes" create portal-ext.properties if it is not there. Add database related entries https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Configuration

Comment: <Resource
 name="jdbc/LiferayPool"
 auth="Container"
 type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
 username=""
 password=""
 maxActive="20"
/> i have created the portal-ext.properties and added the above line and updated the password.

Comment: the following is the server log:

Comment: can you paste your portal-ext content here? This is JNDI stuff

Comment: http://pastie.org/9132670

Comment: http://pastie.org/9132673 is the portal-ext.properties

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51852/discussion-between-lucky-boy-and-asr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create portal-ext.properties file inside classes folder and add following lines.

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=
jdbc.default.password=
```

HTH